# WinAPI equivalent of Win32_ComputerSystem.Domain

Tags: c#, winapi

My app is running on a computer that is joined to an Active Directory domain.  Is there a way to get that domain's DNS name using WinAPI methods?  I want something that will work even if there are no DNS servers or Domain Controllers available.

Right now, the only way I can find is through the Domain property of the Win32_ComputerSystem WMI class:

```
using System.Management;

public class WMIUtility
{
    public static ManagementScope GetDefaultScope(string computerName)
    {
        ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
        connectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        string path = string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", computerName);
        return new ManagementScope(path, connectionOptions);
    }

    public static ManagementObject GetComputerSystem(string computerName)
    {
        string path = string.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", computerName);
        return new ManagementObject(
            GetDefaultScope(computerName),
            new ManagementPath(path),
            new ObjectGetOptions()
        );
    }

    public static string GetDNSDomainName(string computerName)
    {
        using (ManagementObject computerSystem = GetComputerSystem(computerName))
        {
            object isInDomain = computerSystem.Properties["PartOfDomain"].Value;
            if (isInDomain == null) return null;
            if(!(bool)isInDomain) return null;
            return computerSystem.Properties["Domain"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I can find in WinAPI is the NetGetJoinInformation method, which returns the NetBIOS domain name:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PInvoke
{
    public const int NERR_SUCCESS = 0;

    public enum NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS
    {
        NetSetupUnknownStatus = 0,
        NetSetupUnjoined,
        NetSetupWorkgroupName,
        NetSetupDomainName
    }

    [DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected static extern int NetGetJoinInformation(string lpServer, out IntPtr lpNameBuffer, out NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS BufferType);

    [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    protected static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

    public static NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS GetComputerJoinInfo(string computerName, out string name)
    {
        IntPtr pBuffer;
        NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS type;
        int lastError = NetGetJoinInformation(computerName, out pBuffer, out type);
        if(lastError != NERR_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(lastError);
        }
        try
        {
            if(pBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                name = null;
            }
            else
            {
                switch(type)
                {
                    case NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS.NetSetupUnknownStatus:
                    case NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS.NetSetupUnjoined:
                    {
                        name = null;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        name = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pBuffer);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return type;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(pBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to resolve the name but rather get the name of the domain the computer is a member of, did I get that right? I.e. the suffix that gets appended to the DNS name when that machine performs dynamic DNS registration of itself?!

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Right, the domain that the computer is a member of.  I edited the question to try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`GetComputerNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301.aspx) with `ComputerNameDnsDomain` as first parameter. But it's possible that you want one of the other types there. Still, `GetComputerNameEx` is the function you are looking for from how I understand the question.

PInvoke details [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getcomputernameex).

You raise a fair point in your comment, so sure, in this case [`LsaQueryInformationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378313.aspx) with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation` may be the better way to get the DNS name of the domain of which the computer is a member.

But it is a special case and your question didn't mention any such special cases. This should only ever be the case when the primary DNS suffix has been set and differs from the DNS domain name of which the machine is a member. For all practical purposes `GetComputerNameEx` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: In the remarks section for GetComputerNameEx, it says "If you are working with environments that use different DNS layouts, where the computer's FQDN does not match the FQDN of its domain, use LsaQueryInformationPolicy instead".  I think LsaQueryInformationPolicy is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Fair enough, at least I got you on track. Keep in mind: no one other than you can know those details from the question as you gave it :)

Comment: My question might not have been as clear as it could be, but I think asking for the equivalent of Win32_ComputerSystem.Domain gave a very clear description about what I was asking for.  According to the quote I gave, it looked to me that GetComputerNameEx might return something different than Win32_ComputerSystem.Domain.

Comment: I prefer to write code that works all the time.  LsaQueryInformationPolicy with PolicyDnsDomainInformation is the answer.  Thanks for your help.